# Difference between OData complex and entity types

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I am new to OData and haven't yet found a clear answer to what is difference between complex and entity types. So far I only found out that entity type **should have key property**. Are there any further differences and how should they be taken into account when using `ODataConventionModelBuilder`?

Answer (score 2):

## Entities

Entities are instances of entity types (e.g. Customer, Employee, etc.).

## Entity types

Entity types are named structured types with **a key**. They define the named *properties and relationships* of an entity. Entity types may derive by single *inheritance* from other entity types.

The key of an entity type is formed from a subset of the primitive properties (e.g. CustomerId, OrderId, LineId, etc.) of the entity type.

## Complex types

Complex types are **keyless** named structured types consisting of a set of properties. These are value types whose instances *cannot be referenced outside of their containing entity*. Complex types are commonly used as property values in an entity or as parameters to operations.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/data-model?view=odata-edm-7.0

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding an Entity type is a type that can be returned from an EntitySet and a Complex Type is a type that is nested in an Entity Type.  In my experience I rarely have to tell the ODataConventionsModelBuilder about my complex types it just discovers them.